# Google Cloud Build - Custom machine types not working

Tags: google-cloud-build

I already set up custom machine types in the cloud build file.

But, google tall me a warning (Long build duration).

Custom machine types not applied!

What did I do wrong?

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```yaml
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cos-cloud/cos-customizer"
    args:
      [
        "start-image-build",
        "-image-project=cos-cloud",
        "-image-name=${_BASE_IMAGE_NAME}",
        "-gcs-bucket=${_CLOUD_BUILD_BUCKET_NAME}",
        "-gcs-workdir=cloud-build-${BUILD_ID}",
      ]
  - name: "gcr.io/cos-cloud/cos-customizer"
    args:
      [
        "run-script",
        "-env=_MIX_ENV=${_MIX_ENV},_RELEASE_NAME=${_RELEASE_NAME}",
        "-script=cloudbuild.sh",
      ]
  - name: "gcr.io/cos-cloud/cos-customizer"
    args:
      [
        "finish-image-build",
        "-zone=us-central1-a",
        "-project=${PROJECT_ID}",
        "-image-project=${PROJECT_ID}",
        "-image-family=${_IMAGE_FAMILY_NAME}",
        "-image-name=${_BASE_IMAGE_NAME}-${_IMAGE_FAMILY_NAME}-${SHORT_SHA}",
      ]
options:
  machineType: "E2_HIGHCPU_8"
timeout: 3600s
```

**Google's build duration warning**

[image]

Comment: Try with simple quote?

Comment: Insight is just used to give recommendations that use machine learning to provide insights, it’s not a warning. You can read more about it in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/insights/using-insights). Can you please provide us with the [last refresh time](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/using-asset-insights)? It will be helpful to check if the insight is older. Additionally, can you check your Cloud Build’s execution details to check if the machine type is e2-highcpu-8 or e2-medium, and let us know?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere
I founded answer.
Thanks your opinions.

Comment: @ZeenathSN  I founded answer. Thanks your opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a CloudBuild problem.

[cos-customizer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cos-customizer) configures the machine type is impossible.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cos-customizer/issues/79
[image: Answer]